# Virtual mouse as joystick on esp-32 communicating over WiFi

Tags: javascript, c++, embedded, wifi

Theres this app, remotemouse, that displays a trackpad and keyboard, sends data from those over WiFi and moves the mouse or writes text on a pc. I want to implement something similar, but with an esp-32 instead of a phone and a joystick instead of a trackpad.

I already have a (kind of) working version.

I implemented communication using websockets. I transmitted the joystick data on the esp and processed it on the pc. I then used the robotjs library to use this data for mouse movement.

I expected the mouse to move smoothly and almost instantly in relation to my joystick inputs, but it was a bit choppy and delayed.

The esp code, programmed with C++ and platformIO and running as a server:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include "modules/joystick/rjc_joystick.h"

WiFiClient wifi_client;
WebSocketsServer websocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

static const char*  SSID           = "MY_SSID";
static const char*  PASSWORD       = "MY_PASSWORD";

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    // Handle events here
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi ");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.printf("WiFi connected, IP: %s\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
  websocket.begin();
}

void loop() {
  JoystickPosition joystick_position = RJC_JOYSTICK::get_mapped_position(-10, 10);

  // Example: Send joystick position over WebSocket when the joystick is moved
  if (joystick_position.x != 0 || joystick_position.y != 0) {
    // Create a JSON document
    StaticJsonDocument<100> jsonDocument;

    // Populate the JSON document
    jsonDocument["type"] = "cursor";
    jsonDocument["data"]["x"] = joystick_position.x;
    jsonDocument["data"]["y"] = joystick_position.y;

    // Serialize the JSON document to a String
    String message;
    serializeJson(jsonDocument, message);

    // Send the message to all connected clients
    websocket.broadcastTXT(message);

    Serial.println("Sent joystick position over WebSocket: " + message);
  }

  websocket.loop();
  delay(35);
}
```

The back-end pc code programmed with nodejs and running as a client:

```js
let WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
const robot = require('robotjs');

let client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
  console.log('WebSocket Connected');
  connection.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
  });
  connection.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Connection Closed.');
  });
  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (typeof message.utf8Data === 'string') {
        try {
          const data = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);

          const type = data.type;
          const x = data.data.x;
          const y = data.data.y;

          if(type == "cursor") {
            moveMouseWithJoystick(x, y);
          } else if (type == "scroll") {
            robot.scrollMouse(x, y);
          }

          console.log(`[ws]: ${type}: ${x}, ${y}`);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Received non-string data:', message.utf8Data);
      }
  });
});

client.connect('ws://192.168.1.104:81/');

function moveMouseWithJoystick(x, y) {
  let pos = robot.getMousePos();
  pos.x += x + 5;
  pos.y += y + 5;
  robot.moveMouse(pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

Later other group members will write a front end for this as well.
You can look at the complete code [here.](https://github.com/vvnoah/rjc)

Should I be using something other than websockets? I know BLE works (I have working version of this), but I would like to communicate over WiFi because I also plan on adding other WiFi related features later, and connecting the device to a client through multiple protocols doesn't seem great for user experience.

Thanks for any help!